# Trigger application "first open" via CLI?

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, command-line

**Briefly:** I would like to open an application for the first time **from the command line**, and have it act like it was opened in the Finder for the first time.

**In more detail:**

If you download an application from the internet and open it for the first time from the Finder, you get a dialog box asking:

> “MacGuffin.app” is an app downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?

However, if you open the application for the first time from the CLI, it *does not* give you that dialog -- it just opens the application. This seems to be consistent across a few different ways that I've tried to open the application:

- `open -a MacGuffin`
- `osascript -e "tell application \"MacGuffin\" to activate"`
- `osascript -e "launch application \"MacGuffin\""`

In each case, it just opens the app without verifying. Then, later, if you open the application from the Finder, it goes through the whole verifying step.

What I want to do is to trigger that first-open-and-verify behavior from the command line, so that it does not later re-verify it when it is opened in the Finder.

I'm especially flustered since the `man` page for `open` describes its action as "The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon."  *Clearly, it does not.*

Comment: Do you want the dialog to pop up and be clicked or just to do away with that entirely? I'm guessing if we can just suppress entirely the check, you can skip the "I want to trigger" since you only want that if you have to go through that step.

Comment: Does `osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to activate application "MacGuffin"'` cause the dialog to show? Obviously if you already opened MacGuffin, you'll need to try with another app you've not yet opened.

Comment: @bmike The important thing is that it does not ask at a later time. This is part of an installation process-- it would be perfectly fine if the user has to click "OK" to open a file downloaded from the internet.

Comment: @user3439894 This works the same as the two other osascript examples that I gave. It opens the application without going through the verification step. If you open  it after that (from the finder), you'll get the first-time opening dialog.

Comment: Have you tried saving from MacGuffin? Maybe actually saving a project or a file will register better.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Why not just remove the `com.apple.quarantine`  _extended attribute_ from the _file_ and then the User will not get the _... is an app downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?_ to begin with? E.g.: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/filename`

Comment: @jmh, Saving something isn't going to make any difference as it's the `com.apple.quarantine` _extended attribute_ that triggers the message when opened from the GUI.

Comment: @user3439894 That's a possibility, but I *would* ideally like to verify that the application is okay rather than just overriding security.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be opening them from the CLI. That said, that _extended attribute_ isn't going to stop a _bad actor_ with it set either if you allow the app to open from the GUI.

Comment: I'd modify @user3439894's first suggestion slightly to this: `tell application "Finder" to open (path to application "MacGuffin")` (and obviously stick it in an `osascript` command).  I think there's an optional parameter for `open` called `using` or something similar, which allows you to specify an application with which to open a file.  It shouldn't be necessary and seems redundant, but that doesn't make it not worth trying if the first fails: `tell app "Finder" to open (path to app "MacGuffin") using app "Finder"` (or `using (path to app "Finder")`). No computer to test myself currently.